# Error de tipo System.ArgumentException con formularios MDI

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un programa en visual studio, el problema que tengo es que me sale el siguiente error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo **System.ArgumentException** en
>   **System.Windows.Forms.dll**
>
> Información adicional: El formulario especificado como MdiParent para
>   este formulario no es un contenedor MdiContainer.

este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
agregar_productos X = new agregar_productos();
X.MdiParent = this;
X.Show();
```

el mismo código lo estoy usando en otro proyecto y funciona bien, ¿qué podría estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta en que debes establecer a tu formulario actual, desde el cual creas el formulario agregar_productos como MDI, ejemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Aquí indico que mi formulario va ser padre de otras ventanas MDI
        IsMdiContainer = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Este viene siendo practicamente el mismo código tuyo solo que mi formulario es de la clase Form2, por lo demás es igual
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.MdiParent = this;
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias , me ayudaste bastante.

Comment: No hay de que... ;)